# error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated in my code

Tags: c++

I am getting the below error while exporting the dll

"error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated"

Code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::list<DBData> __cdecl FetchTable()
{
std::list<DBData> Test;
FetchData(id, Test);
return Test;
}
```

Comment: thats not  the complete error message, its only the part that tells you that it is an error because you told the compiler to treat warnings as errors. Please include the complete error message

Comment: There is probably a warning about this `std::list<DBData>` which is not portable across other compilers. VS2015 to 2019 are binary compatible but not compatible to previous versions of VS or mingw for c++ based code.

Comment: What's the point in specifying C linkage on a function that you could never use in C?

Comment: The entire posted code falls into [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) land.  I think you need to start from the beginning and figure out another way to marshal data between DLL's.  You can't do it this way.